# Getting the "data" attribute from an <object> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a system loading in a youtube video using an object tag with the id="cstmVideoContent" and the data=(youtube link). I need to extract the content in the object's data property using javascript/jquery and render it elsewhere on the page.

Here's my relevant html:

```
<object id="cstmVideoContent" width="400" height="320" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="NEED THE VIDEO LINK THAT IS HERE" style="visibility: visible;"></object>
```

Based on my admittedly crude knowledge of javascript/jquery, it seems like this should work:

```
var videolink = $('object#cstmVideoContent').attr('data');
```

But it is coming back as "undefined" every time. Is this method possible, am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer : don't use `object#cstmVideoContent` but `#cstmVideoContent`. It will be faster and clearer.

Comment: Code seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/AnXnu/

Comment: Yes, I tested it too. I hope OP doesn't have more than one element with this id.

Comment: Must be where you are placing your script. Make sure it is in $(document).ready() perhaps

Comment: After you all confirmed my JS is valid, I dug into the page and it appears that the object was being loaded in through a JS swfobject.embedSWF line (didn't catch that difference in firebug) - does this mean my method won't work because the HTML is loaded in after the fact?

Comment: @Ryan yes, if the object doesn't exist yet, then the attribute has no value.

Comment: @Mike C., great call on the (document).ready - that solved it. I appreciate you all helping the newibe. Thanks so much! Not sure how to give credit for the answer given the format here.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do for data:

```
<object id="cstmVideoContent" width="400" height="320" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data-link="NEED THE VIDEO LINK THAT IS HERE" style="visibility: visible;"></object>

var personalvideo = $('#cstmVideoContent').data('link');
```

This is based on HTML5, so you'll want to consider testing in several browsers for compatibility.

See: http://api.jquery.com/data/